# DB mail configuration on Azure managed instance

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-managed-instance, azure-managed-database

How to configure dbmail on azure managed instance?

What should be smtp server name? email account?

Will on_prem smtp server work?

And how SMTP authentication should configure on azure mi?

Comment: It's probably too broad for ServerFault, but it is definitely off-topic here.

Comment: Please try to post your code that what have your tried till now, so that we can help you with your code.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL managed instance support [Database Mail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/database-mail/database-mail?view=sql-server-ver15).

[image]

Please learn from the document and it will can help you configure the Database mail step by step.

About your questions, you all can get the answers from the document.

For example:

1. [Configure Database Mail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/database-mail/configure-database-mail?view=sql-server-ver15):
   This topic describes how to enable and configure Database Mail using the Database Mail Configuration Wizard, and create a Database Mail Configuration script using templates.

[image]

Hope this helps.